# How to slice the head of a dataframe until first time TRUE shows up in a certain column?

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

I would like to slice the head of my dataframe after the first time TRUE shows up in a certain column.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(C1 = c(4.32, 8.4, 6.43, 7.98, 5.68, 4.97), C2 = c(4.32, 9.87, 5.43, 6.54, 2.34, 6.59), Logical = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

That the output would look like this:

```
dataframe_new <- data.frame(C1 = c( 7.98, 5.68, 4.97), C2 = c(6.54, 2.34, 6.59), Logical = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Thanks in advance!

It would be great if someone knew how to do it in a list as well...

Comment: What do you mean with slice the head? Get the first n rows after the first occurrence of TRUE?

Comment: like to delete it of the dataframe

Comment: Please give an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach:

- `which(dataframe$Logical == T)[1]` returns the row index of the first occurrence of `TRUE` in the `Logical` column
- `(which(dataframe$Logical == T)[1] + 1)` therefore specifies one row after the first `TRUE`
- `(which(dataframe$Logical == T)[1] + 1):nrow(dataframe)` therefore output rows starting from one row after the first occurrence of `TRUE` to the number of row of `dataframe`, that is the end of `dataframe`

```
dataframe[(which(dataframe$Logical == T)[1] + 1):nrow(dataframe), ]

    C1   C2 Logical
1 7.98 6.54   FALSE
2 5.68 2.34    TRUE
3 4.97 6.59   FALSE
```